# Event Listener for changing input value by user

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am creating a practice project for measurement conversions. I am trying to have an event listener so whenever the input value is changed, the conversions change. I keep getting an error "answer.addEventListener is not a function" and I cannot figure out how to fix it. How can I fix that problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="top">
            <h1 id="header">Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h1>
            <input value="" id="convert" type="number" onchange="calculate()">
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <h1 id="lengthmeas">Length (Meter/Feet)</h1>
            <h1 id="lengthcalc"></h1>
            <h1 id="volumemeas">Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h1>
            <h1 id="volumecalc"></h1>
            <h1 id="massmeas">Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h1>
            <h1 id="masscalc"></h1>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
let number = document.querySelector('input')
let lengthcalc = document.getElementById("lengthcalc")
let volumecalc = document.getElementById("volumecalc")
let masscalc = document.getElementById("masscalc")

let answer = number.value
var change = new Event("change")
answer.addEventListener('change', function() {  
  calculate() 
});

function calculate() {
    let feettometers = answer * 3.218
feettometers = feettometers.toFixed(3)
let meterstofeet = answer/3.218
meterstofeet = meterstofeet.toFixed(3);
lengthcalc.textContent = answer + " meters = " + feettometers + " feet | " + answer + " feet = " + meterstofeet + " meters"

let literstogallons = answer / 3.785
literstogallons = literstogallons.toFixed(3)
let gallonstoliters = answer * 3.785
gallonstoliters = gallonstoliters.toFixed(3)
volumecalc.textContent = answer + " liters = " + literstogallons + " gallons | " + answer + " gallons = " + gallonstoliters + " liters"

let kilostopounds = answer * 2.205
kilostopounds = kilostopounds.toFixed(3)
let poundstokilos = answer / 2.205
poundstokilos = poundstokilos.toFixed(3)
masscalc.textContent = answer + " kilograms = " + kilostopounds + " pounds | " + answer + " pounds = " + poundstokilos + " kilograms"
}
```

Comment: It should be `number.addEventListener...`, not `answer.addEventListener...` because `number` is just a number but `answer` is a DOM element that can have an event listener.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything right, just the problem was that you dont put eventListener to the value of an input, u put it to the input. The below code will work.

```js
let number = document.querySelector('input')
let lengthcalc = document.getElementById("lengthcalc")
let volumecalc = document.getElementById("volumecalc")
let masscalc = document.getElementById("masscalc")

let answer = number.value
var change = new Event("change")
number.addEventListener('change', function() {
  answer = number.value  
  calculate() 
});

function calculate() {
    let feettometers = answer * 3.218
feettometers = feettometers.toFixed(3)
let meterstofeet = answer/3.218
meterstofeet = meterstofeet.toFixed(3);
lengthcalc.textContent = answer + " meters = " + feettometers + " feet | " + answer + " feet = " + meterstofeet + " meters"

let literstogallons = answer / 3.785
literstogallons = literstogallons.toFixed(3)
let gallonstoliters = answer * 3.785
gallonstoliters = gallonstoliters.toFixed(3)
volumecalc.textContent = answer + " liters = " + literstogallons + " gallons | " + answer + " gallons = " + gallonstoliters + " liters"

let kilostopounds = answer * 2.205
kilostopounds = kilostopounds.toFixed(3)
let poundstokilos = answer / 2.205
poundstokilos = poundstokilos.toFixed(3)
masscalc.textContent = answer + " kilograms = " + kilostopounds + " pounds | " + answer + " pounds = " + poundstokilos + " kilograms"
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="top">
            <h1 id="header">Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h1>
            <input value="" id="convert" type="number" onchange="calculate()">
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <h1 id="lengthmeas">Length (Meter/Feet)</h1>
            <h1 id="lengthcalc"></h1>
            <h1 id="volumemeas">Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h1>
            <h1 id="volumecalc"></h1>
            <h1 id="massmeas">Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h1>
            <h1 id="masscalc"></h1>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually you miss one part, `answer = number.value` should be reassign so the value calculated is right

Comment: @DavidYappeter I didn't understand what u mean..

Comment: `calculate()` will be runned, but with the same `answer` value. `let answer = number.value`, it never changed, so you need to add `answer = number.value` inside the eventListener. Like this one https://i.imgur.com/IpnkwnU_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Comment: @DavidYappeter Why is it necessary? Sorry if I am being ignorant to a common fact.

Comment: Well, that's the goal of his code, if the eventlistener works, but the value output isn't right. Either he will need to ask again, or debug it.

Comment: @DavidYappeter But the value is not getting changed, right?

Comment: Yup, if the code is only fixed on the eventListener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242655/discussion-between-archit-gargi-and-david-yappeter).

Comment: Thank you for the help! It turned out adding the answer = number.value inside the EventListener solved the problem.

Comment: By the way which problem?